# Setting length on wrapper functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I often find myself needing to wrap a function on an object for various purposes. Is there an elegant way to preserve the `length` property of the original function on the wrapper function?

For example:

```
var x = {
    a: function(arg1, arg2) { /* do something */ }
};

function wrap(obj) {
    var original = obj.a;
    obj.a = function wrapper() {
        console.log('a called');
        original.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}

x.a.length; // => 2
wrap(x);
x.a.length; // => 0
```

What I would like to do:

```
var x = {
    a: function(arg1, arg2) { /* do something */ }
};

function wrap(obj) {
    var original = obj.a;
    obj.a = function wrapper() {
        console.log('a called');
        original.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    obj.a.length = original.length;
}

x.a.length; // => 2
wrap(x);
x.a.length; // => 2 (actual still 0)
```

However, this doesn't work because `length` isn't writable.

The only solutions I can come up with at the moment are to (1) dynamically generate the function as a string and `eval`/`new Function` it or (2) have a giant array of proxy functions of different lengths and select the proxy function corresponding to the correct length. This doesn't seem like an elegant solution to me, and it seems a reasonable request to be able to create a function with arbitrary `length` *without* specifying each argument in the function.

It seems like `bind` is able to do this internally:

```
function a(b, c) { }
a.bind(null).length; // => 2
```

This creates a wrapper function with the length of the original! That's exactly what I want to be able to do myself.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Does it _have_ to be length? Could you copy that to another property - maybe even add a function to the Function prototype to get either length or your copied variable so the function will return length of wrapped and unwrapped functions?

Comment: just wondering, but what actual _use_ is the `.length` property of a function?

Comment: Yes, it has to be `length`. @Alnitak, I've never used it, but as a framework developer I want to create a general wrapper which mimics the original function, including the `length` property. It's part of the ES spec, and I want my framework to support it, regardless of whether *I* have a use for it. Someone else may.

Comment: @NathanWall given that the MDN version of the shim for `.bind()` can't  reproduce the `.length` property I think it's unlikely you'll be able to achieve what you want other than through nasty `eval` style hacks :(

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Oh well, `eval` hack it is. I think this should be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the eval(...) approach because it's simple.

```
function wrap(obj) {
    var f = obj.fun.toString();
    f = f.replace("{", "{ alert('wrapper'); ");
    obj.fun = eval('['+f+']')[0];
}
```

You could extend this to have 2nd parameter of wrap that represents the wrapper function and get even fancier with the string operations to combine them.

If you're goal is transparency with your wrapping then just make use of the dynamic functionality of the programming language.

---

If you're willing to do extra processing on your JavaScript files you could have your hot patching/wrapping built in.

```
var x = {
    a: function(arg1, arg2) {
        (x._a || (function(){}))();
        ... do actual function stuff ...
    }
}
function wrap(obj) {
    obj._a = function() {
        console.log("ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. You may be right. `eval` may not really be such a bad option here. Thanks for helping me think through it. I'm going to leave the question open for a while to see if anyone comes up with anything else, but so far this is the only real answer. Thanks

Comment: @Nathan Wall - Implementing a version of the "Wrap" function for say 0-9 parameters isn't so bad either, Microsoft uses a very similar approach for it's generic Tuple class in the .Net framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the length of wrapped and unwrapped functions in the same way but can handle not using the length property, something like this might help:

```
Function.prototype.mylengthf = function() {
    return this.mylength | this.length;
};

var x = {
    a: function(arg1, arg2) { /* do something */ },
    b: function(arg1, arg2, arg3) { /* do something else */ }
};

function wrap(obj) {
    var original = obj.a;
    obj.a = function wrapper() {
        console.log('a called');
        original.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    obj.a.mylength = original.length;
}

log(x.a.length); // => 2
wrap(x);
log(x.a.length); // => 0
log(x.a.mylengthf()); // => 2
log(x.b.mylengthf()); // => 3
​
```

Comment: This won't fit my use. I write frameworks, low level abstractions, shims, and patches, and I need my code to be able to be dropped into anyone's project, without teaching them to use `mylength` instead of `length` or forcing them to refactor existing code.